# set the index in a dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, set

I have a problem with set index.
Here is an example.

```
>>> somelist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']
>>> {x:y for x,y in enumerate(somelist)}

{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'A', 4: 'B'}
```

What I actually want is like this:

```
{{0}: 'A', {1}: 'B', {2}: 'C', {3}: 'A', {4}: 'B'}
```

I've tried `{{x}:y for x,y in enumerate(somelist)}` but it doesn't work.

**TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'**

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: When you state that something doesn't work, *include the error message*. In this case I could readily guess as to what goes wrong, but you cannot expect everyone to guess like that all the time.

Comment: You don't want to use a name like `list` in your code; it masks the built-in type. Use `lst` or `somelist` or whatever instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use *immutable* values for dictionary keys. `set()` values are mutable, so these cannot be used:

```
>>> lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']
>>> {{x}: y for x, y in enumerate(lst)}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Use [`frozenset()` values](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) instead:

```
{frozenset([x]): y for x, y in enumerate(lst)}
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']
>>> {frozenset([x]): y for x, y in enumerate(lst)}
{frozenset([4]): 'B', frozenset([2]): 'C', frozenset([3]): 'A', frozenset([0]): 'A', frozenset([1]): 'B'}
```

Dictionary keys **must** be hashable; see the Mapping types documentation:

> A dictionary’s keys are *almost* arbitrary values. Values that are not [*hashable*](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable), that is, values containing lists, dictionaries or other mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity) may not be used as keys.

and the [*hashable* entry in the Python glossary](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable):

> An object is `hashable` if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` or `__cmp__()` method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.

Because `set` values are mutable, they fail the *hashable* criteria; any two sets that compare equal now, can be changed later to no longer be equal, and thus their hash value would need to change too. Because both dictionaries and sets rely on the hash value *not* changing, mutable containers cannot be used as dictionary keys.

Dictionary *values* (as opposed to *keys*) are not restricted to hashable objects.

If you wanted to create set **values** instead, use a loop:

```
dct = {}
for x, y in enumerate(lst):
    dct.setdefault(y, set()).add(x)
```

or use a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object instead and avoid the `.setdefault()` call:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(set)
for x, y in enumerate(lst):
    dct[y].add(x)
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']
>>> dct = {}
>>> for x, y in enumerate(lst):
...     dct.setdefault(y, set()).add(x)
... 
>>> dct
{'A': set([0, 3]), 'C': set([2]), 'B': set([1, 4])}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dct = defaultdict(set)
>>> for x, y in enumerate(lst):
...     dct[y].add(x)
... 
>>> dct
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'A': set([0, 3]), 'C': set([2]), 'B': set([1, 4])})
```

Comment: But why {x:{y} for x,y in enumerate(list)} can outcome {0: {'A'}, 1: {'B'}, 2: {'C'}, 3: {'A'}, 4: {'B'}} ?

Comment: @afternoon: That's because the limitation only applies to keys.

Comment: See the [mapping types documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict); *A dictionary’s keys are almost arbitrary values. Values that are not hashable, that is, values containing lists, dictionaries or other mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity) may not be used as keys.*

Comment: Then I would prefer something like this if it can work {y:{x} for x,y in enumerate(list)}. How to eliminate the "frozenset" after using it? Besides, ([4]) is not {4} which is really what I want.

Comment: @afternoon: `{4}` is a new, literal notation that results in `set([4])`; `frozenset([4])` *is the same thing*, albeit not mutable. Do not confuse the representation of a set with lists here.

Comment: You cannot build the sets with a dict comprehension, but you *can* use a loop to build such sets.

Comment: Oh, if set-wrapping in other types than dict is allowed....why is this not ok? {y:x for x,y in [(y,{x}) for x,y in enumerate(list)]} (still a TypeError: unhashable type: 'set')

Comment: Because you are **still** generating sets for keys with that expression. Using a nested list comprehension does not change that. You swapped `x` and `y` in the outer dict comprehension expression from the inner list comprehension, ending up with the set as the key.

Comment: Is dct.setdefault a dict? How to use .add for a dict?

Comment: @afternoon: `setdefault` is a [method on a dictionary object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault). `dct` is a standard python dict (see the line before it). `dct[key] = value` sets a value on the dictionary.